# Is it Possible to put GridView with baseAdapter in appWidget?

Tags: android, gridview, android-widget, android-appwidget, baseadapter

I am making a calculator widget which have 2 text-views and a gridview with baseadapter but i can't figure out how to put it in appwidget .. it only showing the layout without keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For App Widgets you have to use [`RemoteViewsFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.html) to populate `ListViews` or `GridViews`. Its similar to an Adatper, but it creates `RemoteViews` instead of `View`.

Refer to [this example](http://www.vogella.com/code/com.example.android.stackwidget/src/com/example/android/stackwidget/StackWidgetService.html) for usage information.